# Ошибка "Process finished with exit code "-1073741819" (0xC0000005)" при выполнении java кода в Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Коллеги, добрый день!

У меня проблема с intellij idea при запуске java кода.

При запуске на Run код завершается, недавая мне ввести в консоль значение, с ошибкой "Process finished with exit code "-1073741819" (0xC0000005). (см. скриншот).

Если запуская код с помощью debug, то код успешно выполняется и я могу ввести значение в консоль!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал раза 3 переустанавливать и JRE и JDK + IDEA.

На рабочем компе код исполняется, все нормально. Дело видимо не в настройке java окружения, а компьютера. Но как исправить не знаю.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RoadCamera {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int maxOncomingSpeed = 40; // km/h
    int speedFineGrade = 20; // km/h
    int finePerGrade = 500; // RUB
    int criminalSpeed = 180; // km/h

    System.out.println("Введите скорость автомобиля:");

    int oncomingSpeed = Integer.parseInt((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine());
    if(oncomingSpeed >= criminalSpeed)
    {
        System.out.println("Вызов полиции...");
    }
    else if(oncomingSpeed > maxOncomingSpeed + 19)
    {
        int overSpeed = oncomingSpeed - maxOncomingSpeed;
        int gradesCount = overSpeed / speedFineGrade;
        int fine = finePerGrade * gradesCount;
        System.out.println("Сумма штрафа: " + fine * 2);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Скорость не превышена");
    }
}}
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001834660-Maven-build-results-in-error-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xC0000005-

Comment: отключи Punto Switcher, или обнови, думаю ты им пользуешься

Comment: Вы хоть как-бы отреагировали на рекомендации... Конкретно мне интересно помогло ли это

Comment: @VladZherihov привет! Спасибо огромное! Я только осваиваюсь в stackoverflow))) Советы помогли! Я удалил и переустановил версию PuntoSwitcher на более новую, и ошибка пропала! А как думаете, с чем это могло быть связано? Как это могло вообще влиять на запуск кода?

Comment: я не смогу тебе объяснить почему именно, я могу только предположить. Сначала компилируются файлы, потом идет преобразование в байт-код, где-то на этом этапе влезает Punto Switcher

Comment: Vlad Zherihov, ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо, я мучался с аналогичной проблемой
"Process finished with exit code "-1073741819" (0xC0000005)
очень долго. Чертова PuntoSwitcher, кто бы мог подумать. Мне помогло. СПАСИБО!!

Comment: @VladZherihov Может в ответ перенесёте?